# parachain not producing blocks?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, blockchain, block-production

I am using relay chain of polkadot with branch 1.1.0 of polkadot sdk.
i have my relay chain running with era and epoch time of 2 minutes each . while changing lease period to 10 minutes and keeping lease offset 64 * DAYS i.e default lease period is showing value in minus like -7000.And when i try to add parachain with this values through parasudowraper pallet  parachain is successfully connecting and producing and finalising blocks .

And when i change lease offset period to 2 minutes . the lease period becomes positive according to the state of blockchain . And in this case when i try to connect parachain through parasudo wrapper it is getting connected but not producing and finalising blocks.
Can you please tell why it is behaving like that and how can i successfully connect parachain with block production and finalising